# Liferay : custom Web content Display List Portlet

Tags: liferay

I'm beginner in Liferay, and I need to customize the portlet webcontent display list.

I added a portlet in my page Home, and I managed to see the recent news that I created.
The news is displayed in a table (title, author and date display).
I want to display the news like this:
- The date of the news (above the title of the news)
- The title of the news (which is a link to the news)
I tried to create a structure, but I do not see commits its work?

Thank you to enlighten me?

PS: sorry for this English !!

Answer (score 3):

Liferay is available in source - did you look at the implementation of the webcontent list portlet? You can either create a jsp hook for that portlet or just reimplement a similar one based on what you find in there...

As you say you'd like to customize Webcontent display list I assume you don't want its default behaviour. Once you know what to change in this portlet, read about jsp hooks, create a hook with the jsp changes you'd like (if it's limited to jsp changes) and deploy it.

Liferay's [development documentation](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development) should have the information that you need, otherwise continue in the wiki on liferay.com

**Edit**: Also, you might want to look at AssetPublisher - maybe this provides a few more options for formatting your output.

Comment: See this : http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/12378015

Answer (score 0):

Generally Liferay web content in journalarticle table. I have referred Liferay 6.0 Version.

Now, for showing liferay custom portlet view, you should use Liferay Portlet Creation and Liferay Service Builder.

Here are two useful article on those -
1> [Liferay MVC Portlet](http://www.phloxblog.in/liferay-mvc-portlet-development-startup/)
2> [Liferay Service Builder](http://www.phloxblog.in/liferay-service-builder-step-step/)

Now make the service for journalarticle table and use those in your portlet.

Some useful fields of journalarticle table for your reference are - title, createDate etc.